# Компиляция при помощи gcc

Tags: gcc

Вопрос может показаться глупым, так как опыта в этом у меня нет.
Итак, программа в самом верху имеет строку

```
#include "123.h"
```

Как сказать gcc, что этот файл 123.h нужно искать в определенной директории? Из --help узнал, что есть для опция -B 
Пробую так:

```
gcc -B /path/to/123/ test.c
```

Но всё равно ругается, что не находит файла 123.h

Answer (score 3):

```
#include "/path/to/123/123.h"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36k2cdd4.aspx
Это ЕСЛИ очень "нужно" привязать к конкретной директории, но лучше размещать вспомогательные файлы в относительных путях от билд-каталога

```
#include "../src/inctude/123/123.h"
```

Comment: Ой-вей, почитайте, что ниже ответили, а лучше обновите свой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, вам нужна опция `-I`, а не `-B`.

См. [3.14 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html).

Answer (score 0):

Можно прописать в файле путь к вашему header'у. Это если он лежит не далеко. А вот если например в `/usr/include/123/main/header.h`, компилятору нужно добавить флаг `-I /usr/include/123/main/`. Это скажет ему, где искать твой файл.